# How to terminate processes by name, but not the current process?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

In Delphi 2007, I'm using the code below to terminaet a proccess by its name. It works, but i want to terminate all process with a name BUT the one of the current application. My aim is to close all duplicate process of my app and let only the current one run.

```
function closeProc(pname : string): integer;
const
PROCESS_TERMINATE = $0001;
var
ContinueLoop: BOOL;
FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
Result := 0;
FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
    begin
    if ( UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) = uppercase(pname)) then
        begin
          Result := Integer(TerminateProcess(OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, BOOL(0), FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID), 0));
        end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
    end;
CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

Comment: The treatment of the BOOL variables is a little odd. You can treat them as truth values, no need to be casting to and from integers. Also, there is some erroneous error checking. The repeated assignments to Result mean that your return value relates only to the last call to TerminateProcess. Again a boolean return value might make more sense, once you have fixed it to account for all calls to TerminateProcess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enumerating, compare `FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID` against `GetCurrentProcessId`. If these values match then the process that you are enumerating is the calling process and you can skip the termination code.